# Create button to make twitter doesn't work

Tags: twitter

On my website I pasted link to make a tweet. Link is from this site:

```
http://socialmediasun.com/how-to-make-a-tweet-this-link/
```

and link to make a tweet:

```
http://twitter.com/home?status=Learn%20How%20to%20Make%20a%20Pre-Formatted%20Tweet%20Link%20for%20Instant%20Sharing!%20http://socialmediasun.com/how-to-make-a-tweet-this-link/%20by%20@etelligence%20via%20@Sun_Social
```

It should appear new form with button Tweet, but it doesn't work

Here is button created by the owner of the website and it doesn't work on my twitter account too:

```
https://www.targetinternet.com/how-to-create-pre-written-tweet-buttons-and-links/
```

- example button

---

this link doesn't work too: `https://twitter.com/home?status=kk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That website is outdated - you should follow the official documentation at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/overview

This link will make a Tweet which says "Hello world"

`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world`